# How many Jedi did General Grievous kill?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jedi, kill-count, general-grievous

[General Grievous was a renowned Jedi killer](http://www.starwars.com/databank/general-grievous), who slew dozens of Jedi during the Clone Wars.

Here's a list I found online:

> Daakman Barrek, Sha'a Gi, Tarr Seirr, Soon Bayts, Waldan Bridger, Roron Corobb, T-chooka D'oon, Ur-Sema Du, Firkrann, Adi Gallia, Jmmaar, Roth-Del Masona, Foul Moudama, Nystammall, Pablo-Jill, Puroth, L'lacielo Sageon, B'dard Tone, Flint Torul, B'ink Utrila, Zephata'ru'tor and Nahdar Veb.

However, this list is outdated and incomplete.

Can anyone provide a complete list of all his Legends and canon Jedi victims?

It should also be noted that though he only used four lightsabers, his collection was significantly larger.

Comment: The general rules seems to be "The sillier your name is, the more likely Grievous will be able to kill you."

Comment: Do deleted scenes count? Because Shaak-ti is a limbo death where she is killed by grievous right in front of Anakin and obi-wan in a deleted scene.

Comment: @CBredlow Yes, but please note it in your answer.

Comment: ...not enough!!

Comment: hold on, adi gallia wasn't killed by grevious was she? I'm certain it was by Maul's apprentice (god im amazing with names huh?), the yellow looking one. He killed her didn't he?

Comment: @AlexSpencer I believe *The Clone Wars* animated series retconned it. That is one of the ways the list is out of date.

Comment: @RogueJedi ehh idk. id have thought this internet would have had inconsistencies and stuff sorted out immediately. so many people who have access tot his stuff, im seriously surprised

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL;DR**

**- Canon: 1**

**- Legends: 49** (plus some younglings)

**Canon**

During his career, General Grievous fought many Jedi, managed to capture, if only temporarily, several of them (Adi Gallia, Eeth Koth, Obi-wan Kenobi, Anakin Skywalker), and severely injure others (Depa Billaba as an example). However, I can only find one example in the Canon of a Jedi that he actually killed and that was [Nahdar Vebb](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Nahdar_Vebb), the former Padawan of Kit Fisto, in [TCW 1x10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ihC2vYQj-6w). Grievous may also have been involved in the death of Tu-Anh, which occurs in an [unfinished episode of TCW](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/A_Death_on_Utapau).

**Legends**

Other than that, the list provided by the OP is still fairly accurate in terms of Legends kills, as listed below:

- B'dard Tone, B'ink Utrila, Daakman Barrek, Firkrann, Flint Torul (and 27 other unknown Jedi by destroying the ship that they were on), Flynn Kybo (killed by an explosion that he caused while battling Grievous), Foul Moudama, Jmmaar, L'lacielo Sageon, Nystammall, Pablo-Jill, Puroth, Roron Corobb, Roth-Del Masona, Sannen (killed by one of Grievous' IG-100 MagnaGuards while in combat with him), Sha'a Gi, Soon Bayts, Tarr Seirr, T-chooka D'oon, Ur-Sema Du, Waldan Bridger, and Zephata'ru'tor

Grievous also defeated and left for dead two other Jedi, Quarmall (killing some of his younglings in the process), and K'Kruhk, both of whom survived their encounters.

**Other notes**

- As per the OP's list, while Adi Gallia was originally killed by Grievous, her death was retconned later to be at the hands of Savage Opress in [TCW 5x01](https://youtu.be/aE_CVWMWK74?t=108).
- Even though she was killed by General Grievous in a deleted scene of ROTS, Shaak-Ti's death was never considered Canon since she later appeared in ROTS in a hologram on Kashyyyk. Her death in Canon has been explained to be at the hands of Darth Vader during the [attack on the Jedi Temple](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Attack_on_the_Jedi_Temple).
- As RogueJedi properly pointed out in his comment below this answer, in ROTS General Grievous has four lightsabers already, despite having only killed one Jedi 'on-screen' earlier in the continuity though later in real world viewing (in TCW). This could be explained by the fact that how Grievous came about those four lightsabers at the time of the release of ROTS was explained in the 2003-2005 Clone Wars tv series, which only later was replaced by the 2008 movie/series The Clone Wars. How Grievous already has four lightsabers in TCW, even before killing Nahdar Vebb, from a canon-continuity point of view has not adequately explained.

Comment: Wouldn't Grievous canonically have to have killed at least four other Jedi for his lightsabers?

Comment: @RogueJedi - You're right of course, but remember that at the time of ROTS the 2003-2005 Clone Wars series (which explained where he got his lightsabers from) was still canon, it was only relegated to the dustbin by the 2008 T-canon The Clone Wars 2008 movie/series. Why he has four lightsabers in TCW I don't think has adequately been explained, except continuity from ROTS.

Comment: He presumably has more lightsabers, but uses four because that's how many hands he has.

Comment: @RogueJedi - true, it was mentioned somewhere in Legends that he had favorites, like that of K'Kruhk, so presumably those were the ones he generally used.

Answer (score 5):

**Canon:**

LEAST POSSIBLE MINIMUM: **13** Jedi

*-13 Jedi is the absolute minimum and its almost 100% sure that it were more as it assumes that all his lightsabers he used in the clone wars 2008 series were from the dead jedi he also collected VISIBLE  trophies from in episode 1x10 which were 12 plus the kill of Nahdar Vebb.*

Possible Maximum: **13-21+** Jedi

-Assuming that there were no or only partialy as much as lightsabers in his collection as strands of hair from dead Jedi and he had to replenish them by new kills. We can atleast assume more then 13 kills as parts of the showcases of his strands of hair collection werent visible to the angle or clone troopers staying in front of it. But they were reffered by Jedi Knight Nahdar Vebb as "SO MANY!".

Here is where I draw those information from:
I just counted all the lightsabers from his collection we were able to see to estimate the amount of Jedi he killed in canon.(So the amount of lightsabers or other trophies we saw in ROTS and The Clone Wars 2008)

In the clone wars series Grievous lost several times a saber or was disarmed for example he lost 4 lightsabers alone at his short time capture by the EMP wielding Gungan Grand Army.

**He lost 8 lightsabers during the whole Clone Wars 2008 Series.**

SO if we count every lightsaber he lost during the series and had to replace plus the trophies we see in his secret hideout in TCW 1x10 we can conclude the canon numbers. By doing this I was able to make an estimate on his canon kill count.

**There are 12 visible trophies of murdered Jedi in his secret hideout.
VISIBLE and therefore again a MINIMUM!**

As we arent able to see how big the room is and how many showcases were in it. Also some Clone Troopers partially hindered sight on the showcases.

**Legends**:

MINIMUM: **49** Jedi (and some younglings)

MAXIMUM: **HUNDREDS** as stated by a Jedi in front of the Jedi Council in one of the comics.

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved if you actually *did* what you suggest: counted the lightsabres and made an actual estimate based on that.

Comment: I would have made a comment instead of an actual answer If would have been able to do so. Well fine I will make it a future project of mine as it something you cant realy found a proper answer on the internet.

Comment: Hey I did it! End after watching all battles and scenes involving grievous in the Clone Wars in slow motion were he fought with a Lightsaber I can finaly come up with this numbers.

Comment: Great! Your answer looks *much* better now - have an upvote :-)

Comment: “Jedi” *is* the proper plural of “Jedi.”

Comment: @Adamant: Edited.

Comment: I'm fairly certain he takes light sabers whether or not he killed a jedi. I'm pretty sure there are examples of him keeping them if he disarms or captures a jedi.

Answer (score -2):

But also you have to think on this. In the 10 chapter of the first season of star wars the clone wars "THE LAIR OF GRIEVOUS" there is one scene were Kit fisto and his aprentice enter to the award room were we can se at list 8 padawans ponytail and drawers which contained a lot of ligthsaber that were taken from the jedis Grievous killed. This was only in one little part of the room so imagine how many jedi he killed (ALSO THAT THIS WAS AT THE BEGING OF THE CLONE WARS SO HE PROBABLY KILLED MUCH MORE)

Another evidence is that think how many times grievous loses his ligthsabers A LOT. But every time he lose one he take another and another and another....
Only thinking about how many ligthsabers he will take from the jedi he killed I get gooseflesh.

Comment: How does this answer the question?