# How many lightsabers does General Grievous have?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber, general-grievous

We know [General Grievous was handed his first lightsaber by Count Dooku](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/65700/19561), it having belonged to Sifo-Dyas. We also know [he has four other lightsabers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/132273/19561), having belonged to Pablo-Jill, Roron Corobb, Eeth Koth, and Shaak Ti. And we know [he has killed numerous Jedi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/131760/19561).

But considering he has received at least one lightsaber that had belonged to a Jedi he didn't kill, that he took lightsabers from Jedi he didn't kill, and that he may not have been able to retrieve each and every lightsaber of those he did kill,

**How many lightsabers did General Grievous have?**

Comment: 9 by the looks of it: https://general-grievous.fandom.com/wiki/Grievous%27s_Lightsaber_Collection

Comment: Lots: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EGyfdtW5zn0

Comment: About a dozen and many times more in Legends; https://sabersourcing.com/general-grievous-lightsaber-collection-list/

Answer (score -1):

Combining the whole legends and all canon in star wars he has 30 lightsabers which he took from his victims, while there are additional 9 lightsabers that he was not shown taking from his victims, considering he took them too but just wasn't shown it should total up to 39 lightsabers.
Now there's a good chance that there were many jedi who reclaimed their lightsabers from him like anakin skywalker and obi wan kenobi. And the movies only show grievous wielding some of the many lightsabers he has, but then there's the legends timeline, though lucasfilm has now made the legends timeline non canon, its where grievous claimed majority of his sabers. I myself have not counted them personally but a reputed website does show the numbers I gave.I will add the link to that later when I find it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Can you provide quotes to back up those numbers?  The number itself is only half of the answer, the details are the other half.